# Anime where the main character has a pet squirrel and her friends have powers activated by devices on their wrists

Tags: story-identification, anime

The animation looked like an anime. The main character was a young schoolgirl with short red hair and she had a flying squirrel as a pet. In the beginning she transferred to her grandfather's school, and there she learned that she could summon a machine on her forearm which gave her superpowers of some sort. I was young when I watched it but I remember that she and I think 4 of her friends had these "special powers" that were activated by these machine like things on one of their wrists. I also know there were these two siblings who were famous singers but they worked for the evil ones.

I don’t remember when I saw it exactly but it might’ve been 2010ish. It might have been made in the late 80s or 90s.

Comment: Where did you see this and when?

Comment: [Brothers Conflict](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bv_3DbpEqv0?) has quite a lot of these tropes

Comment: This reminded me immediately of Captain Earth.  But without knowing about when you saw it, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3):

I think [crypto has the right of it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/198605/23243) by stating that it's the Korean animated series *스피어즈*, aka *[Spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheres_(TV_series))*.

[image: Title image for *Spheres* showing the five main characters, include Na Yeon with her pet baby flying squirrel, Nalong]

> Unbeknownst to human history, the Kingdom of Spheres existed upon our earth long ago. The people of this kingdom would be regarded today as people with psychic powers. Unfortunately, like most other civilizations, as the gap widened more and more between the social classes, the Kingdom of Spheres was troubled by those greedy for power; and in the end it collapsed. Na Yeon is a mysterious girl who was found in the Antarctic after the destruction of Spheres. One day Asten, the chairman of Sphere Union, who has a burning ambition to control the world, sent his followers to keep watch on Na Yeon. Na Yeon and her friends try to keep three artifacts, the keys to conquer the world, from the hands of Sphere Union.

Na Yeon has a pet baby flying squirrel, Nalong. The devices they wield are the eponymous Spheres. Her grandfather, Principal An Il Hwan, runs a "school for geniuses" which he built on the ruins of the old kingdom, and runs a "New Spheres" club for Sphere users.

### Trailer

Comment: This was one of those cases where I felt like I'd have to edit too much of their post, so I made my own answer, crediting them.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is Spheres.[image]

Comment: While a picture is worth a thousand words, providing a bit more detail as to what matches up (and anything that may not) would improve this answer. (Yes, I see the small creature on the center girl's shoulder, that she has something odd on her wrist, and that there are five girls).

Answer (score 0):

From the squirrel, could it be
[Magical Emi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_Emi,_the_Magic_Star)?
Emi herself doesn't have red hair when transformed, but in her "normal" state does:
[image]

The Plot has her gandfather and a bracelet as well, so there is a quiet good match :).